# Suppressing premature finalization of stream in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have the following logger-like class pattern:

```
public class DisposableClassWithStream : IDisposable
{
    public DisposableClassWithStream()
    {
        stream = new FileStream("/tmp/file", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string s)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(s);
    }

    ~DisposableClassWithStream()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    private readonly object disposableLock = new object();
    private bool isDisposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (disposableLock)
        {
            if (!isDisposed)
            {
                writer.Close();
                stream.Close();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private FileStream stream;
    private TextWriter writer;
}
```

and a very simple code using this class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new DisposableClassWithStream();
    t.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

The code throws (nondeterministically), both on .net and mono, `ObjectDisposedException` caused by method `Close` of object `writer` as it tries to flush buffer to `stream` which is already disposed.

I understand that the reason is that `GC` finalizes `stream` before `writer`. How can I change the class pattern to be sure that `stream` is not disposed before the `writer`?

I tired to use `GC.SuppressFinalize(writer)` in the constructor, but I'm not sure if it is not too hacky.

**Edit:**

---

I would like to address the question of having finalizer in the first place. As mentioned at the beginning of the question, the class is used as a logger and I want to assure that all lines from `writer` are flushed to the hard disk before closing the process.

Comment: Why do you need to keep stream around?

Comment: Just drop the destructor. Those are not unmanaged resources, they have their own finalizers.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear why there is a finalizer at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not** create finalizer, unless your `IDisposable` implementation really works with unmanaged resources. `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` are managed resources.

Moreover, since [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) was introduced, it is hard to imagine use-case, when any unmanaged resource couldn't be wrapped into managed `SafeHandle`. Do not follow blindly `IDisposable` implemetation from MSDN - it's OK, but it is intended for the case, when your type operates both managed and unmanaged resources.

Remove finalizer at all, and throw away `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` from `Dispose`:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    lock (disposableLock)
    {
        if (!isDisposed)
        {
            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**.

Finalizers are intended for unmanaged resource cleanup.
You may consider finalizer as a place to close file handle, network socket, etc. This isn't a place for any application logic. In general, managed object during finalization resides in unusable state - there's no guarantee, that any of its `IDisposable`s (like `stream` or `writer` in your sample) are not finalized already.

If you want to be sure, that particular log message is flushed into file, than write it and call `writer.Flush()`. Otherwise, if immediate flushing is undesirable for you, make sure, that you're calling dispose for the logger on application shutdown. Also note, that you can't protect from process termination, so don't be too paranoid with your logger.

Comment: `SafeHandle` isn't perfect for everything; some variations on the weak even pattern may need to use finalizers in ways `SafeHandle` can't accommodate.  Even (especially!) there, though, the object with the finalizer shouldn't be public; instead, the public object should hold a strong reference to the finalizable object.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is some nice pattern to manage finalization of group of objects. The best solution is, of course, to dispose the logger object by hand and not rely on finalizers.

Answer (score 1):

Managed objects should not be cleaned up in the finalizer. The finalizer should only used for cleaning up unmanaged resources.

Rewrite your code as follows to dispose of managed resources when you are done with the streams.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var t = new DisposableClassWithStream())
    {
    t.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```

And be sure to check out the [Dispose Pattern article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Clear and concise. You must always check that the finalizer must avoid touching any managed resource as it maybe has been already removed by the garbage collection as it does not follow any order when removing objects.

Answer (score 0):

When a finalizer runs, most managed objects to which it holds references will meet one of the following criteria:

-1- Not care about cleanup, in which case the finalizer should do nothing with them.

-2- Be unable to perform cleanup in a thread-safe manner when invoked in the context of finalizer cleanup, in which case the finalizer should do nothing with them.

-3- Have already cleaned themselves up using their own finalizer, in which case the finalizer should do nothing with them.

-4- Have a `Finalize` method which hasn't run yet, but is scheduled to run at first opportunity, in which case the finalizer for the class holding the reference should do nothing with them.

Different objects will meet different criteria, and it may be difficult to know which of those criteria a particular object might meet, but for the vast majority of objects will meet any of the criteria, the required handling is the same: don't do anything with them in the finalizer.

There are a few rare scenarios involving things like weak events where finalizers may be able to do something useful with managed objects, but in nearly all such cases, the only classes which should have finalizers are those *whose sole purpose* is to managed the finalization cleanup of other intimately-related objects.  If one doesn't understand all the wrinkles of finalization, including the differences between short and long weak references and how they interact with the finalizer, any finalizer one tries to write will likely do more harm than good.